# swift syntax. What is <R> in "withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>(_..."

Tags: swift

I am rather overwhelmed by the extensive syntax of Swift, especially closures.

Can someone kindly parse out the  part of " withUnsafeMutableBytes(_: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R" .

Is there any way to represent this as a function?

Comment: `Is there any way to represent this as a function?` — But it *is* already a function. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: I don't know what kind of thing "R" is (sorry)

Comment: 'withUnsafeMutableBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

Comment: That's a generic notation, and <R> can be anything. Other letters are used as well, but it doesn't really matter. See also ere: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html.

Comment: @koen, it doesn't even have to be a single letter name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` means that:

- Function `withUnsafeMutableBytes` takes a function/closure (that may `throw` error) from `UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer` to some generic type `R`. What `R` depends on the caller.
- Function `withUnsafeMutableBytes` returns value of the same generic type `R` taken function returns. And it may `rethrow` error, if it was thrown by the closure.

So basically generic parameter `R` here is just a way to say that return types of `withUnsafeMutableBytes` and the `closure` it takes will be *identical*, and it's not hardcoded.

Comment: withUnsafeMutableBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R . Thank you very much. However there is an <R> before the first "("  what goes there? I don't understand the syntax

Comment: Generic function syntax is like this `func [name]<[list of all generic parameters]>(<function parameters>) -> [return type]`. And you have to declare all your generic parameters inside of `<>` before using them in further function declaration or function body. `<R>` just means that there would be a generic parameter named `R` used in the function.

Comment: @user28434 You should read the Swift language guide. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html Particularly the section on generics, but more generally, I recommend everyone read it cover to cover.

Comment: @user462990 See my comment above

Comment: Sorry to be so obtuse. I want to access a Data as [Int16].  Is there a way to do this as a straightforward function? I realize there are 2,4,and 8 byte boundary issues, but I would expect a modern language like Swift to hide these from a programmer.

Comment: @user462990, `pointer.bindMemory(to: Int16.self).map({$0})`, where `pointer` — it's parameter of the `closure`. `bindMemory(to:)` turns buffer pointer int0 another type, and `map` creates `Array` from the buffer pointer.

Comment: Thank you again this looks very useful. I've never used a closure yet. I know you so kindly mean to tell me something but I can't get it yet. Can you fill in the ???        let data: Data = NSData(contentsOf: path)! as Data;  var rArray = [Int16]( repeating: 0, count: data.count/2); rArray = ?????